# The local variable cannot be initialized

Tags: java

I am working on this set of code but have run into a " The local variable connat be initialized" error. I am new at writing code in java and I am trying to learn the basics. I understand that the variable needs to be initialized but I do not know how to go about doing it. I understand that I can do "int price = 0;" but that will always return price as $0. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
 Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
 int price;
 String customertype;
 double bonus;
 DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("$#,###");


 System.out.println("Are you a residential (r), commercial (c), Educational (e),  or Preferred (p) customer?");
 customertype = in .next().toLowerCase();
 System.out.println("Please enter the number of minutes the customer used NkuTel services for the week");
 double minutes = in .nextInt();


 //Weekly rate of $5. 10 cents per minute over 60 mins.
 if (minutes <= (0) && (minutes >= 10080)) {
  System.out.println("Cannot have that amount of minutes. Please try again");
  if (customertype.equals("r")) {

   if (minutes > (60)) price = (int)((5 + .010) - 60);
   if (minutes <= 60) price = 5;
  } {}
  //20 cents per minute for first 300. 15 cents per min after that
  if (customertype.equals("c")) {
   if (minutes <= 300) price = (int)(.20 * 300);
   if (minutes >= 300) price = (int)(minutes * (.15));
   if (minutes >= 300) bonus = (price * (-.30));
   System.out.println("You get a bonus for being over 300 minutes!");
  }
  //Educational customer charged 18c per min.
  if (customertype.equals("e")) {
   price = (int)(.18 * minutes);
  }

  if (customertype.equals("p"))
   if (minutes >= 500) price = (int)((minutes * .04) + 10);

  if (minutes < 500) price = (int)((minutes * .06) + 10);

  else
   System.out.println("Error. Please enter either 'r' or 'c'");
 }


 /*Preferred customer pays $10 base and 6c per min. 
 if <500 then rate is 4c per min. */

 //  else{ 
 //  System.out.println("Error. Please enter either 'r' or 'c'");}

 System.out.println("Your total minutes is " + minutes + ", your total bill is " + df.format(price));
}
}
```

Comment: `price` is never initialized in the else block if `customertype` is `e`. You must initialize in all branches.

Comment: What IDE are you using, to give such a badly named error? `javac` says *"variable price might not have been initialized"*, and Eclipse says *"The local variable price may not have been initialized"*, both of which correctly identify the problem, i.e. the fact that the problem is "have not been initialized", unlike the "cannot be initialized" you mention.

Answer (score 0):

you need to initialize price , compiler understands that your price is not being initialized in all cases( in case none of your conditions are true) , either u initialize it  first or put an else and initialize it so you tell compiler that you are initializing it in all cases

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you only set the price when the customer type is "r", "c", "e", or "p". For your program, those are probably the only valid customer types. But the compiler doesn't know that - what if a customer was type "z"? In that case, you can't print out the price because you never set it to anything.

To fix this simply declare your price to start out at 0. `int price = 0;` This won't cause issues with your current code because you will overwrite the `0` value when the customer type is valid.

An even better solution would be to set up your code to handle the case where an invalid customer type is entered. it looks like you tried to do that with `System.out.println("Error. Please enter either 'r' or 'c'");`, but you didn't get it quite right. It might look like this:

```
 //changed this line - it should be if minutes less than 0 or greater than 10000, not AND
 if (minutes <= (0) || (minutes >= 10080)) {
  System.out.println("Cannot have that amount of minutes. Please try again");
 }

 if (customertype.equals("r")) {
  if (minutes > (60)) {
   price = (int)((5 + .010) - 60);
  }else {
   price = 5;
  }
 }else if (customertype.equals("c")) {
  //20 cents per minute for first 300. 15 cents per min after that
  if (minutes <= 300) {
   price = (int)(.20 * 300);
  }
  if (minutes >= 300) {
   price = (int)(minutes * (.15));
   bonus = (price * (-.30));
   System.out.println("You get a bonus for being over 300 minutes!");
  } //fixed this block to include the print only if they actually earned the bonus
 }else if (customertype.equals("e")) {
  //Educational customer charged 18c per min.
  price = (int)(.18 * minutes);
 }else if (customertype.equals("p"))
  if (minutes >= 500) {
   price = (int)((minutes * .04) + 10);
  }
  if (minutes < 500) {
   price = (int)((minutes * .06) + 10);
  }
 }else
   System.out.println("Error. Please enter either 'r' or 'c'");
 }
```

I corrected some other small errors, but I think some might still remain. For example, you calculate the `bonus` for having over 300 minutes, but you never do anything with it. However, I will let you deal with some of those now that I fixed the code to the point where you should be able to run it.

Remember, using braces (`{}`) around your if statement blocks will make it more clear what statements are included in the `if` and what ones are not. I highly recommend always using braces for every if statement even though you don't always have to, especially because your original code had some confusion in that area.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers hit the problem, "price" not being initialized, but since you are "new at writing code", you should realize that such problems can be hidden by how the code is structured and can be avoided with a couple other strategies.

First, ALWAYS use {} around blocks, so this code:

```
if (minutes < 500) price = (int)((minutes * .06) + 10);

else
  System.out.println("Error. Please enter either 'r' or 'c'");
```

would become:

```
   if (minutes < 500) {
       price = (int)((minutes * .06) + 10);
   }
}  // From a prior if statement.
else {
   System.out.println("Error. Please enter either 'r' or 'c'");
}
```

A good IDE, such as Eclipse, can be configured to add those for you.

Another strategy is to avoid the if/else/if "ladder" all together, and use a switch construct.  Note that using Strings in a Java switch is a relatively new feature.

```
// Compute price based on customer type
switch (customertype) {
     case "e":
         // Your code here.
         break;

     case "c":
         // Your code here.
         break;

     case "r":
         // Your code here.
         break;

     case "p":
         // Your code here.
         break;

     // ALWAYS, ALWAYS, ALWAYS use a default: case in a switch.
     // ALWAYS.
     default:
         System.out.println("Error. Please enter either 'r' or 'c'");
         break;
}
```

This construct makes it quite clear where the customers are processed and variables not defined. If there is common processing across customer types, then this might not be a good choice, or you can put such code into methods and call them as needed.